# Wrap Text Inside DataGridCell WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI1hE.png)In my application, I am binding the datagrid. I have written a style for **datagridcell**, all the style properties are getting executed but not **text wrap** property . It is trimming the data inside the cell.

[image]

Comment: You need to show us some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get a WPF Datagrid with cells that wrap text instead of truncating it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671836/how-get-a-wpf-datagrid-with-cells-that-wrap-text-instead-of-truncating-it)

Comment: Edit: Never mind. Found the problem. Check the answer below.

Comment: From next time onwards, please post the code directly, or using a website which allows copy paste. Screenshot of code is useless for others as no one is going to type out your code just to test it.

Answer (score -1):

You are currently creating a style but not setting it to the datagrid. Put the style tags inside the datagrid.

```
<DataGrid --Your datagrid name here--> 
         <Style>                            
           <-- your style code here -->
         </Style>
 </DataGrid>
```

Comment: When i apply the style inside datagrid, it was showing items collection must be empty before using itemssource

Comment: What does style has anything to do with itemssource? Can you update the question with the new code? You know, help us help you?

Comment: <DataGrid Name="dgUsers"  Margin="2" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Black"  AlternatingRowBackground="AntiqueWhite" >               
                <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">                       
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>             
            </DataGrid>

Comment: Remove the Target Type. Also, please use proper formatting for code. You can use help link to understand more about formatting.

Comment: Post a screenshot.